# Customising JAXB bindings for marshling/unmarshling

Tags: jaxb

As per the pasted part from jaxb binding, I have an element name Amt, for which I want to invoke marshling/unmarshling. My question is when the below method will be called?
Is it when any getter and setter methods are called.

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='CreditTransferTransactionInformation1']"><jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='Amt']"> <jxb:property><jxb:baseType><jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" parseMethod="com.anz.ssp.ibank.hostinterface.cim.jaxb.DatatypeConverter.parseDoubleIFXFormat" printMethod="com.anz.ssp.ibank.hostinterface.cim.jaxb.DatatypeConverter.printDoubleIFXFormat"/>
                </jxb:baseType>
              </jxb:property>
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `Amt` property you have used the bindings file to override how a JAXB implementation will handle that value.  This will result in the generation of an `XmlAdapter`.  The `XmlAdapter` will only be invoked during marshal/unmarshal operations are called, and not when get/set are called.